# NoSuchMethodError with Android Lambdas

Tags: android, lambda

I'm seeking to use **Lambda expressions** in my Android project (min sdk: 16, target sdk: 25), but running into many issues.

The first problem is that I am developing and debugging my app using an emulator, deploying and fixing bugs multiple times, when, out of the blue, the application will stop loading altogether.

I get the following stacktrace in my log:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method
>   (Ljava/lang/Object;)V in class Lcom/androidtest/-$Lambda$1; or
>   its super classes (declaration of 'com.androidtest.-$Lambda$1' appears
>   in /data/app/com.androidtest-2/base.apk)

I've enabled the use of lambda expression as described in the android documentation with the following code in my app/build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gfs.mp3lab"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        ...
    }
    ...

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

I took Parth Pandya's suggestion and added the jackOptions paramter in my build.gradle file and believed that to fix the problem, but after rebuilding my project I now sproadically get a different error:

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class
>   'com.gfs.jotsalot.-$Lambda$1' does not implement interface
>   'java.lang.Runnable' in call to 'void java.lang.Runnable.run()'
>   (declaration of 'android.os.Handler' appears in
>   /system/framework/framework.jar)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

Replacing the lambda expression appears to fix the problem, so going from

`() -> { Log.i(TAG, "Hey There"); }`

to

```
new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Hey There");
    }
}
```

works. I'm doing this in a threaded application so I'm not sure if that's the reason for the error and so far I have only tried it on an emulator. Rebuilding the project fixes the problem but that is very time consuming and the hassle has been detrimental to the point where I am removing all of them from my project.

So far I have only tested inside of an emulator and am uncertain if it would affect a genuine phone environment. Because these lambda expressions work just fine (until they don't) I think it is safe to conclude that this is a bug. I was just wondering if it is a known one and if there are any workarounds for it.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552073/no-virtual-method-com-polidea-rxandroidble-internal-radio-rxbleradioimpllambda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parth's answer was helpful, but in the end I kept getting runtime errors using lambda expressions no matter what I seemd to do. Because the Intellij-based IDE represents implementations of single function Interfaces as lambdas visually, I opted to just remove all of them from my project rather than deal with the headache.

Comment: I have the same issue.

I randomly get a NoSuchMethodError showing up from time to time. A project clean up fixes the issue for some time.

This has been reported in the Android issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37563269

Answer (score 3):

In your `build.gradle` file you are missing jackOptions enabled to true just add this to your `defaultConfig` like below and I think it should work.

```
android {
 defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.gfs.mp3lab"
     minSdkVersion 16
     targetSdkVersion 25
     jackOptions {
        enabled true
     }
     ...
 }
 ...

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks- my initial implementation of your answer did not work after doing a clean and redeploy. I had to shut down the emulator and try again but now it looks great.

Comment: Sorry- after revisiting this issue, jackOptions was not the game changer. I'll edit my original question to provide more details.